# How to move my local wordpress to https?

Tags: ssl, https

I've been wondering if there's a chance to supply my local wordpress with a ssl certificate and move it to https? What I mean is while I have my wordpress website locally, I still access it through the web with my external IP address but let's encrypt won't issue a certificate for a bare IP. So how do I make my website secure?

I've tried installing really simple SSL plugin but it won't recognize my self-issued openssl certificate too.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.  In order to understand the reason this question is out of scope, please carefully read the tag description, for [Wordpress](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)

Comment: This isn't a Wordpress question, but if LetsEncrypt needs a host name, why not find a way to give it a host name? This is probably the easiest solution if you're running something like apache or nginx where LE has really great tools for installing their cert. Buy a cheap domain or get a friend to give you a subdomain of their domain?